# Unnamed (anonymous) thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, anonymous, named

I want to understand why I often get the following message when I run my C# project:

> The thread '< No Name >' (0x0000) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I work on a Windows Form project, where I need to use many timers. In the main thread, I use the sleep function `Thread.Sleep()` many times and I also create a child thread that is used to acquire from an external device (e.g. camera) using its own DLL:

```
Thread acquisitionThr = new Thread(acquire());
acquisitionThr.Name = "Acquisition Thread";
```

where the function `acquire()` is declared and defined in the main class (no, there isn't a specific object to manage the thread). Both the main and child threads are named.

When I run the application in debug mode (VS10), I often see in the debugger window the above message, where the thread address may change. My project works fine, but since I'm pretty new to C#, I prefer to understand the origin of this message.

What kind of thread is it? Who created it?

Comment: "Windows internals" book would give you information you are looking for . There is no way to provide smaller and concrete answer based on information you provided about that random thread .

Comment: Ok, thank you. Unfortunately, this is a big old project and I don't know very well the architecture. I'm not the first author of the source code, so I cannot provide better information... Could these threads be caused by the C#/GUI environment?

Comment: Sure. Just look at Debug->Windows->Threads... You'll see "couple" for any process doing OS/.Net background tasks of all kinds - most of them sleeping/waiting for various reasons... Unless you have very specific reason to worry - just let them do whatever they do :)

Comment: Thank you. I was worry that the problem was in the project. My "problem" is that I want to understand this behaviour to better check my code and to be sure of what is happening. Thank you again for the advices!